# iOS 8.0 AppIcon image where does it reside Xcode 6 xcassets doesn't have it

Tags: ios, xcasset, xcode6

[image]

Are they waiting for non-beta to be able to add this icon or does it reside somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably a label not being updated in the beta yet, but my app has been picking up the iOS 7 App Icon in iOS 8.

Comment: it's showing up correctly in the simulator but it's not showing up right when running on the device.